# Hard Limit to SQL Server 2012 Memory Usage

Tags: sql-server-2012, memory, windows-server

It seems that even in SQL Server 2012, the maximum memory usage settings is not a hard limit. I've read some SQLOS Team blogs about this, and those as well as several MSDN articles seem to state that the maximum memory usage is just that - a maximum.  But that doesn't appear to be accurate.  I have a QA environment and the app and SQL are on the same server (this is typical for our application). I've tried setting maximum memory usage to both 8GB and 4GB, but eventually, usually within 24 hours, SQL is utilizing about 13GB (all available) of memory.

Is there an actual way to hard limit SQL Server to not use more than x GB of memory?

Edit: is it possible that the databases themselves being in SQL Server 2008 compatibility mode is causing this?

Target Memory (Performance Counter) is 100% of the 4GB maximum memory value I gave it. Now, of course, it's currently lower because I had to restart SQL Server services to allow anything else to work properly.

select * from sys.dm_os_process_memory:

[image]

[image]

Comment: That is correct, even in SQL Server 2012 this is not covering *all* of the memory SQL Server can potentially use. The prevailing wisdom is to leave some room for memory above and beyond the buffer pool, so if you want SQL Server to use 8 GB total, set max sever memory to something lower (and to measure accurately - where exactly are you seeing 13GB?). How SQL Server could use 13 GB when you've set 4 GB max (you're restarted the service, right?) could only be explained by understanding how you're using SQL Server. And I seriously doubt this has anything to do with compatibility mode.

Comment: (Though, are you keeping your databases in 2008 compatibility mode on purpose? Why?)

Comment: I'm seeing the 13 in task manager, and while I know it's not the most accurate portrayal, SQL is definitely using the memory. This came up due to a change in an IIS Host Service in our application. A new change to it causes the host services to be unavailable if there's less than 5% available memory in the system as a protection. Nothing besides SQL is using even 1GB of memory, and there's only Windows, SQL, and our app.

Comment: The databases are generated via DacPac and we still support SQL 2008. It appears someone has set it to generate with 2008 compatibility mode.

Comment: Stop even opening Task Manager. Seriously.

Comment: While Task Manager may not be great for SQL, it's actually a very useful tool for other application-related things.  Regardless, the application sees less than 5% available memory on a system with 16GB of RAM where only SQL and the application reside, and I killed all app processes and restarted IIS and found the system still had less than 5% available remaining memory.  So regardless of the source of the information, there simply isn't a whole lot of system memory left and SQL is the only plausible culprit currently.  Hence my question.

Comment: In other words, I don't need to profile SQL down to the most precise byte to determine my system is being tanked by SQL :p

Comment: Being accurate is important. Did you look at performance counters? Anyway, there is not much we can do but throw wild speculation at you based on the information provided. You need to look at things like `sys.dm_os_sys_memory`, `sys.dm_os_process_memory`, and `DBCC MEMORYSTATUS` to start tracking down what else is using memory outside of the standard memory manager.

Comment: Can you please add output of `select * from sys.dm_os_process_memory` in the question

Comment: @Shanky I've added the screen from that query.  I get an OutOfMemoryException trying to run `DBCC MEMORYSTATUS`

Comment: Ok as per output SQL Server physical memory utilized is `13.8 G` but the Virtual memory committed is `30G`. So overall memory utilization is `30G. (RAM +Virtual Memory/pagefile)`. Which points to issue that there is lot of paging happening and SQl server is facing memory crunch. So you need to increase memory. What is page file you have set ? What is current Max server memory ?

Comment: So, additional details.  This is a QA system, non-production.  The vast majority of the time, nothing _should_ be happening on the server, SQL or otherwise.  Clearly that's not the case.  The system is a VM that has 16GB of RAM allocated to it that is unshared.  I've set SQL Server to use no more than 8GB of system memory (for whatever that ends up being worth), but it creeps up to all available physical memory every night, so by the time I come in every morning, the system's memory is pegged.

Comment: This is simply because it requires it. To comment more Need to physically look into system did you checked SQL Server is there any paging information.